# Why can't Python3 find Fabric?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I'm having trouble using Fabric with Python 3.

```
$ pip list | grep fabric
fabric (2.4.0)

$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.1

$ python3
Python 3.7.1
>>> from fabric import Connection
Traceback...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fabric'
```

The [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org) documentation says:

> Fabric is a high level Python (2.7,3.4+) library...

Fabric is installed into a virtual environment that contains only Python 2.7.  Python 3 is installed outside that virtual environment.  Is this the reason python3 can't find the fabric package?  I was under the impression that if you activate a virtual environment, all packages installed into the venv are available to any Python interpreter you execute.

Comment: Try `pip3 install fabric`

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  If you want to write that as an answer, I'm happy to give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to install Fabric for python3 in your environment. `pip3 install fabric`